# How to update table1 with content from table2 with php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables in my database, table1 and table2. They are identical. But sometimes I change the data in table1.

How do I copy the data from table1 and update table2 to look the same?

I tried `REPLACE INTO table2 SELECT * FROM table1` but it works like INSERT and just make new rows instead of updating the existing ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `REPLACE INTO` to work as intended, the destination table must have a primary key defined, otherwise MySQL cannot determine whether a row already exists and always assumes a new row. As a result, for tables without a primary key, `REPLACE INTO` acts exactly like `INSERT INTO`.

Alternatively, you can use two queries, one `UPDATE` and one `INSERT`, with appropriate `WHERE (NOT) EXISTS` clauses. The advantage of this is that it's portable (`REPLACE INTO` is a MySQL extension).

Comment: Great. That was my problem. I missed the primary key. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to run two commands...

```
truncate table table2;
insert into table2 select * from table1;
```